# C#: custom array sorting

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I would like to sort an array of strings in a directory, given a custom mapping (it's actually a sorting of stock names based on their sector).  I am unsure of what data structures to use to represent the mapping, and how to write the custom sort method.

So for instance, suppose I had the following string array:

```
string[] fileNames = "bac.csv", "c.csv", "cvx.csv", "java.csv", "msft.csv", "xom.csv";
```

And here are the mappings:

```
{"bac", "c"} => 0
{"msft", "java"} => 1
{"xom", "cvx"} => 2
```

I would like string[] customSort(string[] fileNames) to return the following:

```
"bac.csv", "c.csv", "java.csv", "msft.csv", "xom.csv", "cvx.csv"
```

What data structure would you use to represent the mappings, and what's an elegant way of writing the sort method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Array.Sort allows you to specify an array of keys, so you can do something like...

```
int[] keys = new int[fileNames.Length];

Dictionary<string, int> mapping = new Dictionary<string, int>(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIngoreCase);

// set up our mappings like so
mapping.Add("bac", 0);
mapping.Add("c", 0);
mapping.Add("msft", 1);
mapping.Add("java", 1);
mapping.Add("xom", 2);
mapping.Add("cvx", 2);
// etc

for(int i=0; i < keys.Length; i++)
{
    string token = System.IO.Path. GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileNames[i]);

    int mappingKey;

    if(!mapping.TryGetValue(token, out mappingKey)) mappingKey = int.MaxValue;

    keys[i] = mappingKey; 
}

Array.Sort<int, string>(keys, fileNames);
```

Just modify the `keys[i] = -1;` statement to get the proper value from your mappings given the `token` variable.

Comment: That would require me to write:
key["bac"] = 0;
key["c"]=0;
key["msft"]=1;
key["java"]=1; etc. right?
Is there a more concise way of writing this?

Comment: No, you wouldn't be writing this. I'll edit the code to be clearer and perhaps make it more concise.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but this didn't sort the array as it should.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Um...it seems like if you have your mapping in a usable format, you could just write up a custom [IComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer(VS.85).aspx) implementation and hand it to [Array.Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.sort(VS.85).aspx). Maybe I'm missing some important detail in your question?